# Backup Windows to Server

Tags: windows, backup

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2.  Is there a way for me to back up my PCs to my server so that they can be recovered completely by the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An application such as Symantec System Recovery can back up an image of each system to a server( or almost any storage) but you must use a boot disk to restore the image. It will even restore to different hardware if you are using for Disaster Recovery.